# "... than WERE those of negative age stereotypes" Why is there a "were" in this sentence?

Tags: grammar

The full sentence is: "*Previous studies have indicated that priming effects of positive age stereotypes were harder to observe **than were those of** negative age stereotypes*".

It's from a psychology research paper (DOI: 10.1111/ajsp.12343 / if anyone is interested...)

Could anyone dissect the bolded part and explain as to why it was not written as "than those of negative age stereotypes"? I can intuitively understand the meaning, I cannot understand the function of "were those of" in this sentence, particularly the placement of "**were**".

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Subject + verb inversion](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/165115/subject-verb-inversion) Plus be-deletion in comparisons: She is bigger than Tim [is]. [Comparative deletion](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/472065/a-question-about-comparative-clauses/472085#472085)

Answer (score 2):

In comparisons, sentences of the type

- "Time passed more quickly than (it passed) last year."

are usual: whether you retain the verb (and the pronoun in this case) or not makes little difference to understanding.

*Other examples*

- Isabelle has more books than her brother (has).
- John is more mad than Bob (is).

So, the central part of the question is why is "were" not at the end? Actually, this inversion, known from the times of Chaucer (circa 1340 - 1400), is considered to be rare and on the way out, and it is not recommended; this is what is to be gathered from this [reference](https://thegrammarexchange.infopop.cc/topic/inversion-after-than).

In fact it seems to be far from rare; this can be deduced from the Google pages below.

[to be, lexical verb and auxiliary](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22than%20is%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en)

[to have, lexical verb and auxiliary](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22than%20has%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en)

[to do, pro-form](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22than%20do%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en)

Comment: Inversion is mandatory after "so" in the sense of *also*. She went to Paris, and so did I.

Answer (score 1):

The "were" is added for clarity. Without it, it wouldn't be clear what was hard to observe: we might read the sentence as saying that it's the negative age stereotypes that are harder to observe, rather than the effects.

So the sentence is saying that "priming effects of positive age stereotypes were harder to observe than priming effects of negative age stereotypes", rather than "priming effects of positive age stereotypes were harder to observe than negative age stereotypes".

Answer (score 0):

> ... priming effects of positive age stereotypes were harder to observe than were those of negative age stereotypes

can be simplified as

> Xs of Y were harder to observe than ***those*** [Xs] of Z

***Those*** is a demonstrative pronoun replacing ***priming effects***. As for ***were***, it is redundant and could have been omitted with no change in the meaning. I would personally chuck it out. The author of the sentence might have felt it safer to remind the reader at that point that, 'hey this is a parallel structure, do your homework by guessing what's missing. Ok, I will give you a hint, ***were...***'.

In comparative sentences with ***than*** you can definitely omit the verb, especially if it is the same as in the first part of the comparison, and provided there is no ambiguity. Paul Fanning says on [Guinlist](https://guinlist.wordpress.com/2020/04/13/233-structures-with-a-double-meaning-3/):

> Omitting words to avoid repetition is particularly possible with conjunctions. The conjunction ***than*** is very commonly used with omitted words, especially when the comparison is between two noun ideas.
>
> > Children usually need to sleep longer than adults.
>
> Here, the missing words here are probably the verb phrase ***…need to sleep***, or at least a substitute like ***do*** . We know that a verb is implied because ***than*** is a conjunction, a kind of word that typically links with verbs.

This is what happens in your sentence. You have a comparison between two NPs, ***As were harder to observe than (were) Bs***. To avoid repetition *priming effects* were replaced with ***those*** and the second ***harder to observe*** was omitted. Without avoiding repetition your sentence will be:

> Previous studies have indicated that priming effects of positive age stereotypes were harder to observe than (*were harder to observe priming effects*) of negative age stereotypes.